# Could not get PS2 keyboard to work with Startech KVM

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, keyboard, kvm-switch

I have a Startech 2-port KVM switch I am using between a Windows 7 and Linux box.

Unfortunately I cannot get it to work with a PS2 keyboard that I like (using a PS2-to-USB adapter), although it does work with a USB keyboard.

When I switch to the Windows box, it says trying to install driver and then failed. It even says this with the USB keyboard (and fails), but it works with the USB (even though the "driver installation" failed). On the Linux side, it just completely fails. When the keyboard is plugged in it just blinks all three lights sporadically and is obviously hanging the KVM because the mouse becomes eratic.

I have tried two completely different PS2-to-USB adapters, and both times the same thing happened. The keyboard works fine on both boxes without the KVM switch.

Why would a KVM be installing a driver at all, seems like a security risk. I program sensitive stuff and I do not want KVMs installing software on my boxes.

Comment: A ps2 to usb adapter (I suppose it's mouse-and-keyboard adapter with two ps2 ports) is a composite usb device, not just an usb keyboard. Windows will install a different driver for it.

Comment: @Dan This switch has two USB output ports to the console (one for the keyboard, one for the mouse). The inputs to the boxes, however, are single USB ports that both devices go through.

Comment: The kvm may only do hardware switching of the usb connectors, and the computer will see the actual device. But the usb keyboard and the usb/ps2 converter are different devices, therefore windows will install different drivers.

Comment: Sounds like you need a KVM that supports ps2 devices

Comment: @Ramhound True, but getting IT to buy one will take time. I am mostly just trying to postmortem this and determine what technological brain fart is at the root of the problem for my own aedification.

Comment: Your KVM is the problem.